# How to use the hint operator from mongoDB in strongloop loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to be able to use the hint operator from mongodb in Strongloop Loopback. I've been able to use this operator directly from mongodb but I haven't been able to use it from Strongloop Loopback. How can i use it in there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've not used mongo with Loopback, but I suspect to do this you'll need to drop down to using the adapter directly.  Here is a blog post about doing this with PostgreSQL http://suite.as/using-native-sql-loopback/ which may give you a clue.  Sorry I can't be more directly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$hint` operator directly in strongloop. However there is an alternate way to use it in strongloop.

Suppose your mongodb datasource in loopback name is `mongodb`.

```
//Here app is the loopback app object.
var mongoDb = app.dataSources.mongodb;
var mongoConnector = app.dataSources.mongodb.connector;

var promise = mongoConnector.collection("COLLECTION NAME").find( { $query: {}, $hint: { age : 1 } } )
promise.then(function(value){
    //Process data..
})
.catch(function(err){
    //Error..
});
```